# Как вывести объекты с нужными мне полями из MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
exports.get_emessage = function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
       if(err) throw err;
       const col = client.db().collection('emessage');
       let query = { name: { type: String }, email: { type: String}, message: {type: String}, address: {type:String}, date: {type: Date} }
       col.find(query).toArray(function (err, items) {
           if(err) throw err;
           res.send(200, items);
       });
    client.close();
    });
};
```

Есть вот такой метод. По умолчанию делает выборку из базы все что есть. Но мне нужно выбирать по шаблону именно конкретные данные с конкретными полями. Например есть переменная query в ней уже есть пример данных которые мне нужно. Но когда я закидываю query в find()  оно присылает [] но данные не достает. Облазил много ресурсов но нигде не нашел.

Вопрос: Как сделать выборку именно с нужными мне полями? Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = { name: { type: String }, email: { type: String}, message: {type: String}, address: {type:String}, date: {type: Date} }
```

я не уверен, что монго драйвер понимает, что такое `type: String`, но возможно я не прав

далее, query не передается в `.find()` в вашем коде

если нужно выбрать только некоторые поля, нужно использовать mongo projections, или в options (второй аргумент find) - http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find, или как `.project()` на указателе (find  возвращает указатель): http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#project

Comment: В примере нету. Но в описании описывал что при вставке в find не находит приходит мутой объект